# Android textView width not increasing

Tags: android, textview

I'm new on Android. I want my `textView` in list box to grow automatically depending on the contents. I used `width =wrap_content` and `singleline="true"` but no luck. I tried googling and it seems there are `Autofit textView`. But my requirement is opposite.

My main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/default_window_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/item_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/item_margin"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/itemlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#10d6d6d6"
            android:dividerHeight="1px"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/emptylist"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/default_text_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:paddingStart="1dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:rotation="90"
            android:text="@string/empty_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the listView.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/event_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_vertical_margin"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/s_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="--"
        android:rotation="90"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end_time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rotation="90"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/e_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="--"
        android:rotation="90"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/event_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/list_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/list_vertical_margin"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want the contents @+id/end_time and @+id/event_title to be displayed full and those textView to enlarge as per the contents from DB. If it goes out of screen, there'll be scroll bar.

Comment: try width 0dp and weight as 1 (if you have textview alone)

Comment: show your xml. maybe your textview depends on parent control size.